# Converting AS3 to HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash, canvas

I'm struggling convert this into javascript in Flash CC. I need it in HTML5 Canvas.

But Flash just comment out this script:

```
stop();

function findFrame(event:Event):void{
var frame:int = Math.floor((stage.mouseX/stage.stageWidth) * 900) + 1;
gotoAndStop(frame);
};

addEventListener("enterFrame",findFrame);
```

What it does is to move a movieclip from frame 1 to frame 900, depending on mouseposition in x (horizontal direction).

I tried to convert it:

```
this.stop();

function findFrame(event:Event):void{
var frame:int = Math.floor((stage.mouseX/stage.stageWidth) * 900) + 1;
gotoAndStop(frame);
};

addEventListener("enterFrame",findFrame);
```

But no luck, I get this WARNING:

WARNINGS:
Frame numbers in EaselJS start at 0 instead of 1. For example, this affects gotoAndStop and gotoAndPlay calls.

Any expert that can help me on this? :-)

Comment: JavaScript has no frame-based events (That I know of). Without any context about your application, we can't give you a accurate answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus: OP mentioned EaselJS (http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS) which is a javascript library aimed at flash developers. This is what provides OP with MovieClip/frames functionality.

Comment: @MalteKöhrer: Only after I posted my comment.

Comment: @Cerbrus you are right, I didn't look at the edit.

Comment: I see you're using EaselJS.  Does your design permit using Zoe which converts the swf into a spritesheet that you can play on canvas? http://www.createjs.com/#!/Zoe

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your console output? I would expect an syntax error to be dropped in this line:

```
var frame:int = Math.floor((stage.mouseX/stage.stageWidth) * 900) + 1;
```

**:int** is a type definition - and those don't exist in Javascript.